# Themes not working after 1.8 to 1.9 upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, upgrade

After upgrading Magento 1.8.0.0 to 1.9.2.1 I've found that no themes are working at all. I've copied the exact theme structure from `app/design` and `skin/frontend` and then set the package name in `Settings > Configuration > Design` but no dice. Has anyone else experienced similar problems?

The methods I've used above work on a brand new 1.9.2.1 installation so I know it's not the theme or config causing an issue but I'm struggling to suss out what else could actually be causing it! (I have cleared my cache).

Also - setting the theme as `rwd` doesn't work either.

Comment: Are you symlinking template files? If yes then you have to enable symlinks in administrator panel. Also try copy whole design and skin base/default from fresh downloaded magento instance - so your base/default files will be 100% original. 
Check if you don't have design overriden by System > Design > Add design change. 
Check apache error log if there's no error about including empty filename.

Comment: Have you also made sure your plugins are disabled before testing rwd or default theme?

Comment: I've just logged in and removed every single plugin from the website, retested but it still doesn't pick up my rwd theme.

Comment: Make sure the file owner and permissions are correct too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. There was a custom theme being set from the old Magento website insice `System > Design` (not `System > Configuration > Design`) - silly me...